# Bitcoin Core Desktop Wallet retaining my coins due to Gap Limit being exceeded

Tags: legal

trying to send coins am unable to enter address. have to load from clipboard, cannot copy and paste, address bar goes red, disables send functions. i explore reasons, seems 20 unused address gap limit is probably the reason. researched solutions. only feasible solution seems is sending funds to unused addresses, did so with 11 addresses to no effect -  i am still almost 80 over. looks like i exceeded 20 over a year ago. money sat in desktop wallet unusable for a week now. Block chain is up to date. cannot see any solutions here or anywhere else. 1. can anyone offer a solution? i am on Ubuntu  - maybe there is a terminal gap limit extension solution i am unaware of? 2. how is this possible that an automated system can withhold my own money from me over a technicality which isn't ever flagged to users? is this even legal? will it ever release my funds if i can't sort this problem out and do i have redress if not? seems a ludicrous situation and design flaw. any suggestions or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Bitcoin Core uses a gap limit of 1000 addresses, I very much doubt this is the problem. Can you provide the first few characters of the address you're trying to send to? Specifically, does it start with "1", "3", "bc1q", or something else?

Comment: thanks for the 1000 gap limit info, i wasn't aware of that. seems the problem is fixed now - was at the other end of the transaction, not my end. bitcoin core is still working fine. thanks for your help anyway :-)